# How can I update a case in Salesforce using twilio functions?

Tags: javascript, function, salesforce, twilio

I am using Twilio to integrate Salesforce with Whatsapp. When I get a message I create a case in Salesforce, how can I update the same case with 'closed' status?

I am trying to use this code, but I receive a error message

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const requestPayload = `{"Status":"Closed"}`;
  const stts = JSON.parse(requestPayload);

  getTokenInformation()
    .then(token => {
      const options = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      };
      return got(`${token.instance_url}/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Case/${event.caseId}`, {
        headers: options,
        json: true,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: stts,
      });
```

Error message:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at /var/task/handlers/ZF17ec8620a9320c740bb2f847bb1240b1.js:79:31
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /var/task/handlers/ZF17ec8620a9320c740bb2f847bb1240b1.js:79:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)